# jQuery Carousel item limitation navigation issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, carousel

I have put together a couple of jquery carousel's using either Tiny Carousel or jquery carousel. These are being used to list out blog posts generated through wordpress.

In the case of jquery carousel, once the user has clicked the right arrow past 24 items, the sliding visual changes so that it navigates past all items to the next, instead of just sliding from one to the next.

Is there a limitation on carousels as to how many items they can handle, or is there another way around this problem?

Website currently in use on: http://www.curiousme.com/clients/nickturvey/

If you can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be a limitation, unless is coded explicitly. The problem you are having seem more like bug, your could ping thomaslanciaux4(at)gmail(point)com the creator to report it.

Personally I usually use jCarousel, it is well documented and  provides options for you set values like step size and total items explicitly http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration

Comment: I was looking at source code and found toggles.js... take a look at this code http://jsfiddle.net/zJwnH/, it might make your life simpler ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be sure to check those out. I originally looked at jCarousel but dismissed it for a reason I can't remember. toggles.js was a lazy way to get around the code I needed to auto generate the ID. Thanks again, Rich

Comment: Even though I understand why this should work, I can't get it to work. Is it dependant on jquery version, or me changing anything when using it within a file?

Comment: check if `$('.toggleinfo-button').click(...);` is being executed on domReady, or you could also use `$('.toggleinfo-button').live('click',function(){...})`